# Three js Geometry Explode and change position of each face

Tags: three.js, geometry, explode

I am trying to create an explosing geometry simulation, which means modifying position and rotation (x,y,z) of each geometry's faces in an animation. I am using the `CanvasRenderer`.

[This example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_tessellation) from three.js uses a `ShaderMaterial`. However shaders are not supported outside a webgl context.

I tried playing with the explode modifier in the examples but i can't complete this action.

Is there another solution that does not involves shaders ?

Comment: please help,this is important..

Answer (score 0):

I bet with the canvas renderer your only chance is to manipulate the geometry in Javascript code. You can do the same operations that the shader there does.